# Recompiling PHP with a new version of cURL

Tags: php, linux, curl, centos, recompile

This Stack Overflow question

[PHP use different curl version than is installed in system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815349/php-use-different-curl-version-than-is-installed-in-system?rq=1)

has the comment re recompiling PHP with a new version of cURL

> It wasnt so easy. Adding many various options during configure was
>   quite hard. For the first time I forget about adding mysql support and
>   after new php installation published sites went down.

So given that the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php) and [Compiling php with curl, where is curl installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976971/compiling-php-with-curl-where-is-curl-installed) suggest something like `./configure --with-curl=/usr/bin/curl` in my existing php directory (?) should do the trick and the problems the commenter above had with mysql support and suchlike, this (I think) is my question:

**Is there a way to recompile php with a new version of cURL without losing the previous configuration of PHP?**

I'm running PHP 5.3.5 on CentOS 5.8. It's a Media Temple (DV) server. And my end goal is simply to use [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/) on Wordpress, which requires another plugin, which requires cURL 7.16.2+.

Any assistance in my pickle would be sincerely appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to run again the configure command with the same configure command you used for the previous PHP you are using and then just add the --with-curl=/usr/bin/curl

Comment: Hey @rccoros, thanks for the response. I didn't configure the previous PHP compilation; it's as it was when I purchased it.

Comment: you can actually see the configure script used in the phpinfo();


try creating a test.php with <? phpinfo(); and you can see the configure script there.